# Unable to retrieve data from a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am unable to retrieve data from a promise using then(). Where am I going wrong?

```
async function A(){
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(()=>{},1000));
    return 45;
}
A().then(data => console.log(data))
```

I'm running this code with nodejs. 
I expect the output to print 45. But the program just executes for 1 second and doesn't print anything. 
If I remove the timeout statement, I am able to print 45.
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to resolve your promise and then `return` can run.

```js
async function A() {
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000));
  return 45;
}
A().then(data => console.log(data))
```

You could also return promise from `A` function and then use `async/await`.

```js
function A() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(45), 1000)
  })
}

(async() => {
  const res = await A();
  console.log(res)
})()
```

Comment: Thanks Vracar, that worked, Since I have not resolved the promise, can you explain me why the program stopped after 1 second instead of awaiting indefinitely (The promise being in pending state).

Comment: It stopped at the `await` keyword because there code waits for the promise to be resolved. But since your promise never gets resolved, `return` is never called.

Comment: Yes, why did the `await` stop the program execution instead of waiting for the promise to get resolved? The code that I've posted never reached the `return` statement but it stopped execution after 1 second. I am unable to understand why it stopped instead of waiting.

Comment: @John Bonda I am not sure what are you asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your function A should return a promise.

```js
function A() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve('hello'), 1000));
}
A().then(data => console.log(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Function A should return a promise and use async/await along with IFI (Immediate Function Invocation method)

```
function A(){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(()=>{resolve(100)},1000));
    }
    (async () => {
    var data = await A()
    console.log(data)
    })();
```